# Retrofit response returning null in Android

Tags: android, retrofit

I wanted to display a text from a `JSON` value. I'm using `Retrofit` to make `API` call I don't know if I'm doing it right. Anyway here's my code.

Here's the url link: http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random .

The website will display a random joke each time. Here's the example of an output from the website:

```
{ "type": "success", "value": { "id": 175, "joke": "When Chuck Norris was a baby, he didn't suck his mother's breast. His mother served him whiskey, straight out of the bottle.", "categories": [] } }
```

---

**fragment.java**

```
    String url = "http://api.icndb.com/";

    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

    RetroFitHelper client = retrofit.create(RetroFitHelper.class);
    Call<Api> call = client.findJoke("random");

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Api>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<Api> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

            String result = response.body().getJoke();

            Toast.makeText(getContext()," The word is: " + result ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext()," Error..." ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

---

**RetroFitHelper.java**

```
public interface RetroFitHelper {

    @GET("/jokes/{random}")
    Call<Api> findJoke(@Path("random") String random);

}
```

---

**Model class**

```
public class Api {

    @SerializedName("joke")
    private String joke;

    public String getJoke() {
        return joke;
    }

    public void setJoke(String joke){
        this.joke = joke;
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you have added INTERNET permission in manifest

Comment: Thanks but it is already enabled.

Comment: looks like your model class is not quite right. Take a look at Navaneet's answer

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The provided json response has a json object named `value` inside another json object(It is of the form `{..,"value":{}}`). So we need two model classes - one for the `outer json object` and another one for the `inner json object`(value).

You will need to have two model classes like this

```
public class Api {

@SerializedName("type")
@Expose
private String type;
@SerializedName("value")
@Expose
private Value value;

public String getType() {
return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
this.type = type;
}

public Value getValue() {
return value;
}

public void setValue(Value value) {
this.value = value;
}
```

and the following one for value object

```
public class Value {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("joke")
@Expose
private String joke;
@SerializedName("categories")
@Expose
private List<Object> categories = null;

public Integer getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getJoke() {
return joke;
}

public void setJoke(String joke) {
this.joke = joke;
}

public List<Object> getCategories() {
return categories;
}

public void setCategories(List<Object> categories) {
this.categories = categories;
}

}
```

Now, `response.body()` will have the result of `outer json object(Api)` and `response.body().getValue()` will have the result for `inner json object(Value)` .

Now in your response callback, get response like this

```
String result = response.body().getValue().getJoke();
```

> Also make sure that you have the necessary internet permission declared in your manifest like this

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

> Do ensure you have the latest dependencies setup in your **`app level`** `build.gradle` file

`implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'`

`implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'`

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. I have a quick question, how to output the full URL after GET request has been sent? In other words, I just want to output the full URL in case there is some error with onResponse. Thanks again.

Comment: what errors exactly? suppose your response is not successfull, then add your message(or url to be output) as a toast inside `if(!response.isSuccess()){ }` within your `onResponse` callback

Answer (score 5):

As @Aswin suggest and @Navneet answered you have problem in your POJO class.
I suggest you to use [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) or [RoboPOJOGenerator](https://github.com/robohorse/RoboPOJOGenerator) so next time you avoid to stuck this kind of error.

Steps

1) Go to http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

2) Paste your response over there and enter package and class name

3) Choose target language as Java or Kotlin(if you are using)

4) Source type as Json

5) Annotation style as Gson

6) Click Preview

7) Copy and paste those classes to your app package

Comment: that website was really helpful, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Their is a problem in your model class which you are using.

The response of api is :

```
{
"type": "success",
"value": {
    "id": 429,
    "joke": "Chuck Norris has never been accused of murder because his roundhouse kicks are recognized as &quot;acts of God.&quot;",
    "categories": []
}
}
```

So for getting value of joke from response as a string your model class should be like this :

```
public class Api implements Serializable {

@SerializedName("type")
@Expose
private String type;
@SerializedName("value")
@Expose
private Value value;

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public Value getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(Value value) {
    this.value = value;
}
}
```

and your Value Class is :

```
public class Value implements Serializable
{
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("joke")
@Expose
private String joke;
@SerializedName("categories")
@Expose
private List<Object> categories = null;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getJoke() {
    return joke;
}

public void setJoke(String joke) {
    this.joke = joke;
}

public List<Object> getCategories() {
    return categories;
}

public void setCategories(List<Object> categories) {
    this.categories = categories;
}
}
```

And now you can get your value like this :

```
 call1.enqueue(new Callback<Api>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Api> call, Response<Api> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                String jokeValue = response.body().getValue().getJoke();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Api> call, Throwable t) {

            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

Do changes as per you requirement.

*Happy Coding..*

Answer (score 1):

Add this permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Add this in your `build.gradle (Module:app)`

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
```

Add this interface ,

```
public interface ApiInterface {
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://api.icndb.com";

@GET("/jokes/{random}")
Call<Api> GetApiResponse(@Path("random") String random);


public class ApiClient {
    public static ApiInterface apiInterface;

    public static ApiInterface getApiInterface() {
        if (apiInterface == null) {
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
            apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
            return apiInterface;
        } else {
            return apiInterface;
        }
    }

}


}
```

Create 2 Model Class : `com.example.app.Api.java`

```
package com.example.app;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Api {

@SerializedName("type")
@Expose
 private String type;
@SerializedName("value")
 @Expose
 private Value value;

 public String getType() {
 return type;
 }

public Value getValue() {
return value;
}

}
```

Create Value Model Class : `com.example.app.Value.java`

```
package com.example.app;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Value {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("joke")
@Expose
private String joke;

public int getId() {
return id;
}

public String getJoke() {
return joke;
}

}
```

Add this code in your Activity `onCreate()` Method

```
  ApiInterface.ApiClient.getApiInterface().GetApiResponse('random').enqueue(new Callback<Api>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Api> call, Response<Api> response) {
                  String Joke=response.body.getValue().getJoke();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Joke, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Api> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a good way to do it, but worked for me

```
    val json = JSONObject(Gson().toJson(response.body().data)).toString()
Gson().fromJson(json, User::class.java)
```

My response structure was :

```
{
  "success":true,
  "data":{
     "p1":32,
     "p2":34
      },
  "message":""
}
```