# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.yinkyade.scheduler.model.User.getId()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile

I'm trying to retrieve data from currently logged in user using shared preference, but while trying to log in the app crash with the following error `java.lang.NullPointerException`: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.yinkyade.scheduler.model.User.getId()' on a null object reference

**Database Structure**

```
    "user=" : {
      "id" : "1",
      "email" : "yinkyade@gmail.com",
      "user_id" : "CSE/005",
      "password" : "123456",
      "name" : "yinkyade",
    }
```

**Shared preference class**

```
    package com.yinkyade.scheduler.storage;


     import android.content.Context;
     import android.content.SharedPreferences;

     import com.yinkyade.scheduler.model.User;


public class SharedPrefManager {

    //singleton class
    private static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "my_shared_preff";

    private static SharedPrefManager mInstance;
    private Context context;

    private SharedPrefManager(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    //sync method to get singleton instance
    public static synchronized SharedPrefManager getInstance (Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new SharedPrefManager(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public void saveUser(User user) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        editor.putInt("id", user.getId());
        editor.putString("email", user.getEmail());
        editor.putString("user_id", user.getUser_id());
        editor.putString("name", user.getName());

        editor.apply();
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getInt("id", -1) != -1;
    }

    public User getUserlogin(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            return new User(sharedPreferences.getInt("id",-1),
            sharedPreferences.getString("email",null),
            sharedPreferences.getString("user_id",null),
            sharedPreferences.getString("name",null)
        );
    }

    public void clear(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.apply();
    }
       }
```

**Model class**

```
    package com.yinkyade.scheduler.model;

public class User {

    private int id;
    private String email,user_id,name;

    public User(int id, String email, String user_id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.email = email;
        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
       }
```

**Login Activity class**

```
    public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button buttonlogin;
    private EditText editText1, editText2;
    TextView textView;
    LoginResponse loginResponse;
    private static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "my_shared_preff";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        editText1 = findViewById(R.id.editText_userid_login); //emailaddress editext
        editText2 = findViewById(R.id.editText_password_login); //password editext
        buttonlogin = findViewById(R.id.button_login_main); // button  login
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView_register_main); // register/signup textview editext

        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SignUpActivity.class));
            }
        });

        buttonlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                UserLogin();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).isLoggedIn()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, LandingPage.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }// if user is logged in

    private void UserLogin() {
        String user_id = editText1.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = editText2.getText().toString().trim();

        //validations
        //user_id
        if (user_id.isEmpty()) {
            editText1.setError("User ID is required");
            editText1.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        //password
        if (password.isEmpty()) {
            editText2.setError("Password required");
            editText2.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        //validating password length
        if (password.length() < 6) {
            editText2.setError("Password should be atleast 6 character long");
            editText2.requestFocus();
            return;

        }

        Call<LoginResponse> call = RetrofitClient
                .getInstance()
                .getApi()
                .UserLogin(user_id, password);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {

                 loginResponse = response.body();

                if (!loginResponse.isError()) {

                     SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                     .saveUser(loginResponse.getUser());

                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, loginResponse.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,LandingPage.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, loginResponse.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }


      }
```

**StackTrace**

```
2020-06-15 15:55:34.183 30615-30615/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.sys.activitylog"
2020-06-15 15:55:34.188 30615-30622/? E/kyade.schedule: Unable to peek into adb socket due to error. Closing socket.: Connection reset by peer
2020-06-15 15:55:34.631 30615-30647/? E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
2020-06-15 15:55:39.742 30615-30615/com.yinkyade.scheduler E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
2020-06-15 15:45:06.020 27419-27419/com.yinkyade.scheduler E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.yinkyade.scheduler, PID: 27419
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.yinkyade.scheduler.model.User.getId()' on a null object reference
        at com.yinkyade.scheduler.storage.SharedPrefManager.saveUser(SharedPrefManager.java:34)
        at com.yinkyade.scheduler.activities.LoginActivity$3.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:104)
        at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1.lambda$onResponse$0$DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:82)
        at retrofit2.-$$Lambda$DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$3wC8FyV4pyjrzrYL5U0mlYiviZw.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6819)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:497)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:912)
```

**Login Response class**

```
public LoginResponse{

  private boolean error;
  private String message;
  private User user;

  public LoginResponse (boolean error, String message, User user){

   this.error = error;
   this.message = message;
   this.user = user;

}

  public boolean isError(){
   return error;
}

  public String getMessage(){
    return message;
}

  public User getUser(){
    return user;
}

}
```

**Login Response server**

```
loginResponse = {LoginResponse@11408} 
 error = false
 message = "Login successfull. Welcome, ADEROJU ISRAEL"
 user = null
 shadow$_klass_ = {Class@11284} "class com.yinkyade.scheduler.model.LoginResponse"
 shadow$_monitor_ = 0
```

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace?

Comment: Can you please post your login response. The issue is at line `SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                     .saveUser(loginResponse.getUser());`. To the figure exact cause of exception please post Response from server and also LoginResponse class code.

Answer (score 0):

Here the `user` you pass to `saveUser` is null; so in Retrofit `onResponse()` callback, check if the response isn't null before getting their data.

```
    call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {

             loginResponse = response.body();

            if (!loginResponse.isError() 
               && loginResponse != null 
               && loginResponse.getUser() != null) {

                 SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                 .saveUser(loginResponse.getUser());

                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, loginResponse.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,LandingPage.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, loginResponse.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm no longer getting the NullPointerException, but the landingpage activity isn't opening after clicking on login button

Comment: Please check the retrofit interface URI of the get request

Comment: Retrofit URI interface is working fine I tried debugging it and it's was throwing Java.lang.NullPointerException (not as stacktrace this time but debug variable)

Comment: @AderojuIsrael please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47949874/retrofit-response-returning-null-in-android)