# Why do I get Null after I put into MutableLiveData in android

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, null, retrofit

I tried to get weather imformation by using OpenWeatherAPI.

So I used Retrofit library.

API connection was successful.

But the problem is weather data that I got from OpenWeatherAPI
suddenly become null after I put the data into a MutableLiveData.

Here's the code

```
package wook.co.weather.models.repository;

import android.util.Log;

import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import wook.co.weather.interfaces.OpenWeatherAPI;
import wook.co.weather.models.dto.OpenWeather;
import wook.co.weather.models.retrofit.RetrofitService;

public class OpenWeatherRepos {
    private final String TAG = "OpenWeatherRepository";
    private final static String BASE_URL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/"; 
    private static OpenWeatherRepos instance;
    private Retrofit retrofit;
    private OpenWeatherAPI opwAPI;
    private MutableLiveData<OpenWeather> data;

    public static OpenWeatherRepos getInStance() {
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new OpenWeatherRepos();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public MutableLiveData<OpenWeather> getWeather() {

        retrofit = new RetrofitService().getRetroInstance(BASE_URL);

        opwAPI = retrofit.create(OpenWeatherAPI.class);

        data = new MutableLiveData<OpenWeather>();
        callWeatherAPI();
        Log.i(TAG,data.getValue().toString()); //error occurs here
        return data;
    }

    private void callWeatherAPI() {

        Call<OpenWeather> call = opwAPI.getWeather("seoul","this is my id","kr");

        call.enqueue(new Callback<OpenWeather>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<OpenWeather> call, Response<OpenWeather> response) {
                OpenWeather temp = response.body();
                Log.i(TAG,"API CONNECT SUCCESS");
                if(temp != null){
                    Log.i(TAG,temp.toString());
                    data.setValue(temp);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<OpenWeather> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG,"onFailure : "+t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

}
```

This is the result of this code

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: wook.co.weather, PID: 10063
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{wook.co.weather/wook.co.weather.view.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String wook.co.weather.models.dto.OpenWeather.toString()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String wook.co.weather.models.dto.OpenWeather.toString()' on a null object reference
        at wook.co.weather.models.repository.OpenWeatherRepos.getWeather(OpenWeatherRepos.java:46)
        at wook.co.weather.viewmodels.MainActivityViewModel.init(MainActivityViewModel.java:25)
        at wook.co.weather.view.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10063 SIG: 9
```

How can I solve this problem??

Comment: Assuming `opw` is an instance field, what does `call.enqueue(...)` do?  Does the code need to wait for a response?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrofit response returning null in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47949874/retrofit-response-returning-null-in-android)

Comment: I did made a model Class of OpenWeather so I think that doesnt answer my question @Zain

Comment: call.enqueue(..) is the part that connect's with the api and get weather information. and the code doesnt need to wait for the response @AndrewS.

Comment: I corrected my question.
please check my question again @Zain

Comment: I corrected my question.
please check my question again @AndrewS

Comment: Could it be that you're not setting the type when instantiating `data` in `getWeather()`

Try changing 

`data = new MutableLiveData<>`

to 

`data = new MutableLiveData<OpenWeather>()`

Comment: I tried but nothing changed @manbradcalf

Comment: @superRookie Can you post the exception now after this change in text not an image

Comment: I have correct the post @Zain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the problem is here:

> ```
> if(temp != null){
>     Log.i(TAG,temp.toString());
>     data.postValue(temp);
>     Log.i(TAG,data.getValue().toString());
> }
> ```

The `postValue()` method does not update the value of the LiveData immediately; rather it posts a task to the main thread that will eventually update the value. Documentation here: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/MutableLiveData#postValue(T)

This means that calling `postValue()` and then immediately calling `getValue()` will cause you to receive the "old" value (from before you posted a new value), since the task won't have completed yet and updated the value of the LiveData.

The fix, in your case, will be to simply delete the second `Log.i()` call. You *could* modify it to work, something like this:

```
data.postValue(temp);
OpenWeather value = data.getValue();
if (value != null) {
    Log.i(TAG, value.toString());
}
```

But this really doesn't provide any benefit; you already know that `data.getValue()` is going to be out-of-date at this point.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this time I have a another null issue. I have changed data.postValue() to data.setValue(). So after that I've tried to see the data inside but I faced the same null issue. I have correct my question so you could see more information about my question. Thank you.

Comment: This is basically the same issue. You're now trying to log the result of `getValue()` immediately after starting an async api call. Just delete this second log call; it doesn't provide any benefit.

Comment: And it is likely incorrect to use `setValue()` in your `onResponse()` method, since it's unlikely that you're on the main thread at that point.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. null issue is solved!!